# How to pass params with history.push (search + pathname) in react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I need to pass params with history.push in react-router v4.

Specifically `pathname` and `search`.

`history.push(targetLocation.pathname + targetLocation.search)`

Now it works because I use string concatenation. Maybe it's possible to convey without concatenation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```js
history.push({
pathname: '/home', 
search: `?q=query` 
});
```